# Keyboard and mouse only working after reboot

Tags: keyboard, login, mouse, reboot

I'm currently running 14.04 beta on a Lenovo Thinkpad Twist (s230u). As the OS boots into the login screen, the built-in mouse and keyboard are disabled. The touch screen remains active, however.

I've found a way around this: using the touch screen I reboot the system. As it boots for the second time, the keyboard is functional. The mouse however remains inactive until i log in.

I've experienced the same issues on 13.10. Any help is appreciated. Thnx!

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in several Linux distributions with keyboard/trackpad recognition.

You can fix with this line to /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.nomux=1 i8042.reset"
```

Then update grub file with `sudo update-grub`

Check this [link](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=49&t=157115&p=813402&hilit=thinkpad%20twist%20touchpad#p813402) for details (this is for Mint distro, but same issue).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but found a solution by changing my BIOS settings of my Lenovo Flex 15 Easypad.  I had to change the BIOS-setting "UEFI optimized for Windows 8" (was preinstalled on this laptop, I erased it and installed Lubuntu 14.04) to "Other OS".  That did the trick for me.